# Use variable for array key naming inside Ember class

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ecmascript-6

I have an Ember component class as below;

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import myappconstants from '../utils/constants';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    constants: myappconstants.FIELD_CONSTANTS.SECTION_1,
    myConfigs: {
        [myappconstants.FIELD_CONSTANTS.SECTION_1.FIELD_1] : {fieldName:"my__label__1", type:"text"},
        [myappconstants.FIELD_CONSTANTS.SECTION_1.FIELD_2] : {fieldName:"my__label__2", type:"text"}        
    }
})
```

My question is in my component class, I want to have the "myConfigs" keys defined in a slightly different way. This is because the definition can grow to around as many as 20 items & any name change in future would have to be done in multiple places.

So I want it to be defined as

```
myConfigs: {
        [this.constants.FIELD_1] : {fieldName:"my__label__1", type:"text"},
        [this.constants.FIELD_2] : {fieldName:"my__label__2", type:"text"}      
    }
```

With the above code, I get an error;
Cannot read property 'constants' of undefined

Is it possible to achieve the above naming ?

Comment: Note that these aren't array keys, they're property names (`myConfigs` is a non-array object).

Comment: In that code, `this` doesn't refer to your instance. To access `this`, you'd need to override [`init`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.2/classes/Component/methods/init?anchor=init) and run code inside it. (But I don't know the Ember-specific details other than that it's `init`, so can't post an *answer*.)

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/218196), expect this is for keys instead of values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [computed property](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.2/functions/@ember%2Fobject/computed) if you want to make `myConfigs` dependent from `constants` property

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `willRender` hook that you'll get with the component class, and use the `.set()` to set your `myConfigs` property.

It would look something like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import myappconstants from '../utils/constants';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  willRender() {
    const sec1Constants = myappconstants.FIELD_CONSTANTS.SECTION_1;

    this.set('myConfigs', {
      `${sec1Constants.FIELD_1}`: {fieldName:"my__label__1", type:"text"},
      `${sec1Constants.FIELD_2}`: {fieldName:"my__label__2", type:"text"}    
    });
  }
});
```

Note: If you choose to do any sort of `.set()` on `myConfigs`, you'll want to use an Ember Object instead of a POJO for the set object.